# How to set default page in HTML help workshop

Tags: chm, help-authoring, html-help-workshop

I have created a project in HTML help workshop. When I open the help (/chm) application, I could see table of contents. By default, first entry in the file is selected.

However I couldn't see the corresponding page data instead I am able to see "This program cannot display the web page" (default error message that comes in IE7). The page is displayed only when I click on any of the contents on the left side.

Is there a way of showing the page by default with out clicking on the entry?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been a couple of years since I last used HTML Workshop and I don't have it installed anymore but I just checked out some old doc sources and there's the following entry in the .hhp-file:

```
[OPTIONS]
Default topic=index.html
```

I'm pretty sure there was some way to set this via the HHWS GUI, too.

Answer (score 2):

Steps for setting the Default page from the HTML Help Workshop GUI:

- go to "Project" tab
- double-click any item in the "[OPTIONS]" list. Opens the "Options" window.
- select "General" tab
- select/write the file path and name in the "Default file:" combobox
- press OK

Answer (score 0):

The OP did not say "Yeah, it worked", so I am going to add something, as the next time you write a HHW project, if you spent some time without writing one, depending on the authoring tools you use, you have a high probability to commit this error.

I often had that display, but only in one precise case : the paths to the pages were given as absolute paths, which in no case exist in a chm file.
You must start where the project is.
From
C:\HTML Help Project\TestProject\SomeFolder\SomePage.html
do not link to
C:\HTML Help Project\TestProject\SomeOtherPage.html

but rather to
..\SomeOtherPage.html

and also in the [Files] section of the project, avoid the absolute paths. Rather start from the project folder, as I said.

That was particularly frequent for links as in BlueGriffon, I forgot to check the checkbox to make the link relative to the document, which unfortunately does not appear to be the default value.

Not sure but I think I remember this error is also documented for pages on a unit to which the path is not supported : UNC paths, some network units ...

Comment: they don't need to say "yeah it worked". That's largely what the purpose of the accept feature is (green check mark).

Comment: OK, now that you said there was a green check mark, I searched for it and found it.
Noted for next time, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Take the properties of the file in the explorer, and see if it is unblocked, and unblock it else.

Since XPsp2 or so, CHMs are blocked from properly displaying after downloading (or copying of a share in some cases)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but by default most servers will serve index.htm(l) if that is found in a folder.

You might try to name one of the files that, and see if that helps.

Comment: It's HTML Help. No server is involved.