# How to set the default page for a .CHM file in HTML Help Workshop?

Tags: html-helper, chm, help-authoring, html-help-workshop

When I open the help (.chm) application, I could see table of contents. By default, the first entry in the file is selected, however I couldn't see the corresponding page data. Instead, I see "This program cannot display the web page" (the default error message that comes in IE7).The page is displayed only when I click on any of the contents on the left side.

Is there a way of showing the page by default without clicking on the entry?

The following code is the .hhp file.

```
[OPTIONS]
Compatibility = 1.1 or later
Compiled file=Config.chm
Contents file=Config.hhc
Default topic=D:\apps\bin\Debug\html\Databases.htm
Language=0x409 English (United States)
Display compile progress=No
Title=ETL_Config Documentation

[FILES]
D:\apps\bin\Debug\html\Databases.htm
D:\apps\bin\Debug\html\InstanceInformation.htm
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set default page in HTML help work shop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945254/how-to-set-default-page-in-html-help-work-shop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default topic should reference a relative file name inside the .CHM file, not a file outside of the .CHM.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
I did find out is was the setting issue.